# How may I get TemplateRef<T> without creating dummy component?

Tags: angular

I want to get `TemplateRef<T>` as **provided** value.

For example:

```js
export class SumDirective {
  constructor(
    @Inject(SUM_TEMPLATE) 
    private providedTemplate: TemplateRef<ISumTemplateContext>
  ) {}
}
```

But the only way to get a `TemplateRef<T>` that I know is to create component with `<ng-template>` in it's template:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'sum-template',
  template: `
    <ng-template #template let-data>
      <pre>a + b = {{ data.a }} + {{ data.b }} = {{ data.sum }}</pre>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class SumTemplateComponent {
  @ViewChild('template')
  public template: TemplateRef<ISumTemplateContext>;
}
```

I've wrote an example using this approach, but it looks some messy.

[Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndhuf2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

So, my question:
**How may I get `TemplateRef<T>` for dependency injection with more correct way?**

P.S. Actually, this question is about customizable components (e.g. complex select)

Comment: how will you be able to `provide` a template? How will you fill injection token `SUM_TEMPLATE` with the right value? I don't see a way on how to make that work. Perhaps you should rethink the way you want to do what ever it is you want to do :) Or perhaps I'm not seeing it straight.. could be as well

Comment: @PierreDuc I've attached working example to the question, but I want to make it more correct...

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at the material library and how they do lazy rendering for the [menu component](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#lazy-rendering) using a [directive](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/menu/menu-content.ts) on a `<ng-template>`

Comment: Interesting, but I want to get the opposite situation.
This case useful for single using: template for **single** menu in application.
But I want to get opportunity initialize several components in different places with **same** template.
So, I don't want provide in this way **same** template in every *menu* case in app (DRY principle).